# Simple Comonads in Scala?

Tags: functional-programming, scala

```
 trait Comonad[M[_]] {
   // map
   def >>[A,B](a: M[A])(f: A => B): M[B]

   // extract | coeta 
   def counit[A](a:M[A]): A

   // coflatten | comu
   def cojoin[A](a: M[A]): M[M[A]]
}

object Comonad {

  implicit def listComonad[A]: Comonad[List]
  =
    new Comonad[List] {

      def counit[A](lsa: List[A])
      =
        lsa match { case List(a) => a }

      def cojoin[A](lsa:List[A]): List[List[A]]
      =
        List(lsa)

      def >>[A,B](lsa: List[A])(f: A => B): List[B]
      =
        lsa map f
  }

}
```

So yeah I'm looking at this and I don't have that correct feeling...

Anyone mind correcting this and maybe offerring one or two other simple comonads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, what's bothering you is a non-total definition of `counit`, right? (for `cojoin` one possible variation is `lsa.tails`) Indeed, a `List` does not have a valid comonad instance specifically bacause of that. It does have a valid [semicomonad](http://mth.io/talks/zippers-and-comonads/#/44) [instance](http://mth.io/talks/zippers-and-comonads/#/46) though.

Things that have a valid comonad instance are, for example: [Identity](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Id.scala#L16), [NonEmptyList](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/NonEmptyList.scala#L117), [Zipper](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Zipper.scala#L365), [Tuple](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/Tuple.scala#L65-L76). Here's a [reddit question](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/18mtrb/comonad_questions/) with more examples of comonads.